# как убрать 6 символов слева при вводе данных с sql в строке?!1)0

Tags: php, html, dle, site

имеется код вывода новостей из бд. при выводе данных из строчки "xfields" у всех ссылок в начале строки выводится "image|" как его убрать чтоб осталась только ссылка?
Пример получаемой строки
"image|https://mc-heads.net/avatar/uuuuuno/30/nohelm.png"

```php
<?php
  $host = 'да';  
  $user = 'да';    
  $pass = 'да'; 
  $db_name = 'да';  
  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name); 

 
  if (!$link) {
    echo 'Чета с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
  }
?>

<!--news-->
<?php
  $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM `dle_post` ORDER BY `id` DESC');
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo<<<HTML
        <div class="">
           <div class="news">
               <div class="mt-3 mb-2" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;;">
                    <div class="p-3">
                      <div class="row align-items-start">
                          <div class="col-10">
                        <h5>{$result['title']}</h5>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-2">
                            <img src="https://mc-heads.net/avatar/{$result['autor']}/30/nohelm.png" style="border-radius: 5px;">
                         </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-dark">{$result['short_story']}</div>
                        <p>
                          <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#news{$result['id']}" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-chevron-compact-down" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.553 6.776a.5.5 0 0 1 .67-.223L8 9.44l5.776-2.888a.5.5 0 1 1 .448.894l-6 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.448 0l-6-3a.5.5 0 0 1-.223-.67z"/>
                          </svg>
                          </a>
                        </p>
                        <div class="collapse" id="news{$result['id']}">                        
                          <div>
                            {$result['full_story']}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
HTML;
  }
?>
```

Comment: `echo str_replace('image|', '', 'image|https://mc-heads.net/avatar/uuuuuno/30/nohelm.png');`

Comment: ооо, эти знаменитые xfields в dle. если уж приходмтся копаться в этой куче, то надо использовать **стандартные средства dle** для работы с такими полями